# oracle functional index performance

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, query-performance

I have a table with 226 million rows that has a varchar2(2000) column. The first 10 characters are indexed using a functional index `SUBSTR("txtField",1,10)`.

I am running a query such as this:

```
select count(1) 
from myTable 
where SUBSTR("txtField",1,10) = 'ABCDEFGHIJ';
```

The value does not exist in the database so the return in "0".

The explain plan shows that the operation performed is "INDEX (RANGE SCAN)" which I would assume and the cost is 4. When I run this query it takes on average 114 seconds.

If I change the query and force it to not use the index:

```
select count(1) 
from myTable   
where SUBSTR("txtField",1,9) = 'ABCDEFGHI';
```

The explain plan shows the operation will be a "TABLE ACCESS (FULL)" which makes sense. The cost is 629,000. When I run this query it takes on average 103 seconds.

I am trying to understand how scanning an index can take longer than reading every record in the table and performing the substr function on a field.

Followup:
There are 230M+ rows in the table and the query returns 17 rows; I selected a new value that is in the database. Initially I was executing with a value that was not in the database and returned zero rows. It seems to make no difference.

Querying for information on the index yields:
CLUSTERING_FACTOR=201808147
LEAF_BLOCKS=1131660

I am running the query with AUTOTRACE ON and the gather_plan_statistics and will add those results when they are available.

Thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: What is the output if you call `SET AUTOTRACE ON` before?

Comment: Can you add the exact definition of your index in your question as well?

Comment: "Count(1)" -- same as count(*) but not the standard syntax for it.

Comment: How many rows are returned by that query, and what is the clustering factor of the index?  It might be faster to read all the blocks of the table with multi-block IO than read many blocks in the index with single-block IO.  Can you add the results of this query (make sure stats are up to date): `select owner, index_name, clustering_factor, num_rows, leaf_blocks from all_indexes where index_name = 'index name';`  Also, for a query performance problem you should always post the full explain plan using `explain plan for select ...;` and `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);`.

Comment: There are 230M+ rows in the table and the query returns 17 rows. The results of the above query: CLUSTERING_FACTOR=201808147, LEAF_BLOCKS=1131660

Answer (score 3):

There's a lot of possibilities.

You need to look at the *actual* execution plan, though.

You can run the query with the `/*+ gather_plan_statistics */` hint, and then execute:

`select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(null, null, 'ALLSTATS LAST'));`

You should also look into running a trace/tkprof to see what is actually happening - your DBA should be able to assist you with this.

Comment: Here is the index syntax: "create index myTable_IDX1 on myTable (SUBSTR(txtField,1,10))"